# Time - Specify X seconds / minutes, and basic arithmetic

Tags: java, time

I am wondering how one would go about specifing a certain amount time, say X seconds. I'm writing the behaviour for a class that represents a Till (as in, a supermarket till), and whish to specify how long it takes to check out 1 item.

I'm doing this so once I receive the number of items a customer has, the time taken to serve the customer is simply:

```
ITEM_CHECKOUT_TIME * NumberOfItems;
```

ITEM_CHECKOUT_TIME would be a constant, and what I wish to specify. Some basic arithmetic would be done on this constant, like above.

Sure, I could use a double to represent the time, but I was wondering if it's actually possible with the Time classes, or anything else specifically for this task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a `double` to represent time. I would probably represent it as a whole number of milliseconds (or nanoseconds). If you're looking for something fancier, you might want to look at the `Duration` class in the Joda-Time library:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_duration.html